# SQL - counting WHERE AGGREGATE>1

Tags: sql, aggregate, informix

Imagine I have a db table of Customers containing {id,username,firstname,lastname}

If I want to find how many instances there are of different firstnames I can do:

```
select firstname, count(*) from Customers group by 2 order by 1;

   firstname | count(*)
   ====================
   bob       |   1
   jeff      |   2
   adam      |   5
```

How do I count the number of firstnames that occur more than once? In pseudo-sql it would be something like:

```
select
    COUNT(
        firstname,
        count(*) as num_occurrences
    )
from 
    Customers 
group by 2 
having num_occurrences > 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

You have the right idea:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT firstname
  FROM Customers
  GROUP BY firstname
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
)
```

The subquery counts the first names that have occurred more than once. Then you count all of those first names. The `HAVING` clause allows you to filter by aggregates. It's like a `WHERE` clause, except you can use aggregate functions.

Comment: That's overcomplicated - IniTech's answer is better.

Comment: I prefer the idea of this solution because the database is only returning what I'm interested in. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in Informix. :(

Comment: Then you don't include the column in the SELECT clause.  Subselects & subqueries should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: This will work in IDS 11.50; it might work in IDS 11.10; it will not work in earlier versions of IDS - the support for 'sub-queries in the FROM clause' was added quite recently.

Comment: @rexem: @IniTech's answer is not answering the question.

Comment: @Jonathan: This answer isn't referencing the correct column either, and my subquery comment stands (support aside).

Comment: @rexem: agreed that the question is confused about firstname vs username.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a subquery.

Try:

```
SELECT firstname, COUNT(*)
  FROM Customers
 GROUP BY firstname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ORDER BY firstname
```

Or, order by the most represented name:

```
SELECT firstname, COUNT(*) AS custcount
  FROM Customers
 GROUP BY firstname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ORDER BY custcount DESC;
```

Comment: Should be referencing `username`, not `firstname`.  It also isn't providing the requested answer - the count of the number of usernames which have more than one row.  If an INTO TEMP followed by SELECT from the temp table doesn't count as a sub-query, you can do that - but otherwise...

Comment: @Jonathon: The output isn't going to make sense without showing the username the count applies to.

Comment: @rexem: the question asks for the number of customers with more than one entry in the table with the same username.  It does not ask for the usernames, per se; it asks for the number of such usernames.  It is a classic aggregate-of-aggregates query, and the sub-query-in-the-FROM-clause is the best way to answer it.

Comment: @IniTech: looking at the question again, it seems to be a bit confused between username and firstname.  The sample query selects on firstname, but the putative query result lists username.

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
select count(username)
  from (select username
          from Customers
         group by username
        having count(*) > 1);
```

Comment: NB: question was confused about username vs firstname - this answer used 'username' where the revised question goes with 'firstname'.